# set outer scoped variable from inner scope in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var lat = 0.0;
var lng = 0.0;
var jsonData = null;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var miles = $('#milesAway').val();

// find what the user is locating by
if ($('#zipCode').is(':visible'))
{
    var zipText = $('#zipCode').val();
    if (isValidUSZip(zipText))
    {
        geocoder.geocode( {
            'address': zipText
        }, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            } else {
                alert("Zip Code couldn't be located.");
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Please enter a valid US zip code.');
    }
}
```

lat and lng are still set as 0.0 after this thing runs through, why? Shouldn't I be able to set these like this?

Edit: I get to the point where they are supposed to be set too, if I put an alert there I can see the values that they are supposed to be set to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `geocoder.geocode` callback isn't running immediately, it's delayed until the AJAX call comes back.  There's nothing wrong with the scope, the variables just won't be changed until the XHR is done.

If you're depending on them being changed, try putting your dependent code (or a call to a function) within the geocoder callback function.

Comment: i see so its running through and executing other code without running the geocode success method first. gotcha. thank you

Comment: @Scott Can you please fiddle the solution?

Comment: @Dhaval - This question is 2 years old.  StackOverflow is a resource, not a place for people to get other people to do their work for them.