# How to pass variables values from .post response to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to run Geocode from Google Maps Api with my wp-admin plugin. I have my own post type where is input for address of place, and jQuery code watching for click on div.
So that's my code:
**Plugin Code [PHP]:**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_generate_geocode', array($this, 'generate_geocode') );
[...]
//here is my test function that is waiting for response and doing something.
public function generate_geocode() {

    print_r($_POST);
    die();
}
```

**AJAX Code [JS with jQuery]:**

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var lat = '';
var lng = '';

jQuery('#generate-geocode').on('click', function() {
    var address = jQuery('#address').val();
    // alert(address);
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {
        //alert(status);
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            alert(lat + ' ' + lng);
        }
    });
    data = {
        action: 'generate_geocode',
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng
    };
    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        alert(response); 
    });
});
});
```

My problem is that I don't know how to pass lat and lng variables or it's values (value of results[0].geometry.location.lat() and results[0].geometry.location.lng()) to my PHP code. So for a now I have in my alert:

```
Array
(
 [action] => generate_geocode
 [lat] =>
 [lng] =>
)
```

Can You tell me how to pass that values? And maybe there is better way? :)

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is pretty similar to this one:

[set outer scoped variable from inner scope in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587708/set-outer-scoped-variable-from-inner-scope-in-javascript?rq=1)

The code after the geocoder.geocode is actually running before the function responds, so you'll probably want to put your jQuery.post within the call-back function to make sure the variables are set when you need them.

Comment: Yes, you're right. :) I putted code into callback and everything is ok :)